# PostgreSQL: How to use the array contains operator with array_agg function to find matches

Tags: arrays, postgresql, jsonb

I have two tables in a PostgreSQL database I need to join

t1 looks like this

```
    create table t1 (id int primary key, fid int, name_1 text, name_2 text, name_rank int);

insert into t1 values (1, 456, 'Natasha Romanoff','Natasha Romanoff',1 );
insert into t1 values (2, 456, 'Black Widow','Black Widow' );
```

a feature can have 1 or multiple rows grouped by fid ordered by name_rank the two name columns are either the same or name_2 has diacritics exchanged "café" => "cafe"

t2 looks like this

```
create table t2 (id SERIAL primary key,  feat_id int, name_1 text, name_2 text, alt_names jsonb);
```

alt_names is dynamic in that the keys are not known something like this

```
    insert into t2 (feat_id, name_1 , name_2 , alt_names) values ( 456, 'Natasha Romanoff','Black Widow' ,

   '[
    {
        "name:en": "Black Widow",
        "name:en": "Natalia Alianovna Romanova",
        "name:rs": "Наталья \"Наташа Романоф\""
    }
   ]'
);
```

Each feature has 1 row name_2 might be null with all other names within alt_names as shown

I can do this to create an names array from t1

```
select id, array_agg(array[name_1,name_2]) AS names1
from t1
group by id,fid;
```

t1_array might look like

```
    'Natasha Romanoff','Natasha Romanoff'  -- Row 1
    'Black Widow','Black Widow'  -- Row 2
```

At this stage 1 array per row

and this will create an array from the t2.alt_names jsonb if the keys are known

```
SELECT t.id,  array_agg(ARRAY[
   ARRAY (
   SELECT jsonb_array_elements_text(t.alt_names->'name:en')AS alt_names1
   ),
   ARRAY(  
   SELECT jsonb_array_elements_text(t.alt_names->'name:rs')AS alt_names2
   ) 
   ]) 
   FROM t2 t
   group by id;
```

This produces `error:   ARRAY types text and text[] cannot be matched`

And it's not dynamic

```
SELECT t.id,  array_agg(ARRAY[name_1,name_2,
   ARRAY (
   SELECT jsonb_array_elements_text(t.alt_names->'name:en')AS alt_names1
   ),
   ARRAY(  
   SELECT jsonb_array_elements_text(t.alt_names->'name:rs')AS alt_names2
   ) 
   ]) 
   FROM t2 t
   group by id;
```

How do I create the t2 array combining all the name columns   `array_agg(array[name_1,name_2,alt_names])` ?

t2_array might look like this

```
'Natasha Romanoff','Black Widow','Natasha Romanoff','Black Widow','Наталья \"Наташа Романоф\"'
```

Once I have the two array How do I use the contains operator @> to find a match?
It wouldn't matter if either arrays had duplicates

```
SELECT array[t1_name_1,t1_name_2] @> array[t2_name_1,t2_name_2,t2_alt_names] AS RESULT
OR
SELECT array['Natasha Romanoff','Natasha Romanoff'] <@ array[ 'Natasha Romanoff','Black Widow','Natasha Romanoff','Black Widow','Наталья \"Наташа Романоф\"'] AS RESULT
```

That returns True

```
SELECT  array[ 'Natasha Romanoff','Black Widow','Natasha Romanoff'] && array['Natasha Romanoff','Natasha Romanoff']  AS RESULT
```

Also returns True

BTW: if there two or more matches MIN(t1.name_rank ) wins

The end result would be a look up table something like this

```
create table t1_linked_t2 (id int primary key, t1_fid int, t1_name_1 text,, name_rank int t2_name text, t2_id); 

    (1,456, 'Natasha Romanoff',1,'Natasha Romanoff', 2 );
```

From that further analysis can be made

In a nutshell make 2 lists / arrays of names 1 from each table and find any name in t1 that is also in t2

I hope this now makes sense

Here is a [dbfiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_12&fiddle=aa16cd422406babaa776c84a08cba50d) with some dummy data showing my thought process

Comment: Why is the `alt_names` in `t2` an array, not just an object with multiple keys? Or is it always an array containing exactly a single object?

Comment: "*How do I create the t2 array*" - so you mean that `t2.alt_names` is null, like in your fiddle, and you want to fill it?

Comment: Thanks for the fiddle, but could you maybe remove the irrelevant columns, and tell us what exactly the desired result looks like?

Comment: Please re read as I have made edits hopefully answering your comments  and better explaining what I'm trying to do

Comment: t2 alt_names is how it's shown above

Comment: I think this question is in two parts 1) how to build the arrays 2) How to compare them